# Formal definition of “counterexample”.

Tags: reference-request, definition, examples-counterexamples

What is the preferred formal definition of “counterexample” as in: zero is a counterexample for "every integer is either positive or negative". Where in the literature is the notion of “counterexample” formally defined? And what are the main theorems involving this notion? And what questions concerning it remain open?

Comment: From my dictionary: "An example that refutes or disproves a proposition or theory."

Comment: The Goldbach hypothesis has not been refuted or disproved. Thus in your dictionary's sense, it has no counterexamples. Would any mathematician say; "The Goldbach hypothesis has no counterexample"?

Comment: What? It hasn't _yet_ been refuted or disproved, but that doesn't mean there doesn't exist an example that refutes or disproves it. We just might not have found it yet. (On the other hand, a mathematician _would_ say, "The Goldbach hypothesis has no _known_ counterexample.")

Comment: It's like the difference between saying "It hasn't been disproven" and "It has no disproof." The first is true, the second is unknown.

Comment: In [this puzzle](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/37776/1766), my answer was ok but my hypothesis found a counterexample.

Comment: I am grateful for the five "answers".. However, the question is not about making up definitions: it asks for the definition or definitions in the literature that are preferred by mathematicians. As of now, we have zero answers. BTW, by formal, I just mean precise enough to be used to prove theorems and make conjectures.

Comment: @JOHNCORCORAN, most mathematicians don't worry about the precise definition of the word "counterexample", because we usually take logic and/or a fair amount of set theory as "given" and go from there. However, my answer is specific enough that it can actually be used. Try looking for a counterexample to $\forall x \in \mathbb{Z}(x \in 2\mathbb{Z})$, for example.

Answer (score 24):

First a joke: I don't know what a counterexample is, but I can recognize one when I see one.

*In a first order context*, something like the following begins to capture the notion. Let $T$ be a theory over the language $L$. and let $\phi$ be the sentence  $\forall x_1\dots\forall x_n\psi(x_1,\dots,x_n)$.

Then a counterexample to $\phi$ in the context $T$ is a model $M$ of $T$, and elements $a_1,\dots,a_n$ of $M$ such that $\psi(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ is false in $M$.

A related formal notion is that of *semantic tableaux* as used in systems of *natural deduction*. Because it is of interest in Computer Science, there is a considerable recent literature.

Comment: I am not sure this answer is really useful, but it sure brings  some amusement.  Likely you only meant to use one type of phi.

Comment: @quid Why do you think this is not useful?

Comment: @quid: One could extend to $\forall\exists\forall\exists\cdots\psi$, and it would be useful to do so, or just use the definition of truth. I chose the simpler albeit limited path.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I believe he's right in that you must've meant only one of $\phi,\varphi$.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: Yes, I am so used to typing \varphi for the Euler $\varphi$-function that it slipped in. Thanks, fixed.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD It's not clear what level of understanding the asker has, so this answer might be over the asker's head (it's over mine). That's my guess for why quid suggested it might not be useful - the implication being that it might not be useful *to the asker*.

Comment: @ToddWilcox: It is an interpretation of the term "formal" in the question. I agree that it may well be an overly formal interpretation of "formal."

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I upvoted it. And I can piece it together enough to see what's going on enough to feel comfortable with that upvote. If the asker is not yet at university or is in their first or second year, it might be hard for them to connect this with their level of understanding. If that's the case, it's fair to consider the asker responsible because they did not specify their current amount of mathematical knowledge.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD in my mind, the answer is either too complicated or  too simple/short. Thus, it serves no actual useful purpose; in my mind it is a typical case of a vanity-answer. (Or not meant quite seriously, but it seems excluded now.) It also does not answer several questions asked in OP.  Now, essentially no-one answered those. Why? Well, because the question seems a bit based on a false premise. Yet, this answers feeds into it. Or, there may be some corner of (mathematical) logic, where this is actually considered. But then this answer does not address a specialist request.

Comment: Say there is a conjecture of the form $\Psi:(\forall x\in X)(\forall y\in Y)\psi(x,y).$ Someone identifies an $a\in X$, and produces with it a proof that $(\forall y\in Y)\psi(a,y)$ is false, without being able to identify any particular $b\in Y$ such that $\psi(a,b)$ is provably false. Has this person found a counterexample ($x=a$) to $\Psi\,$?

Comment: @JohnBentin: I would be of the opinion that the person has found a counterexample. That is covered by the definition offered in the answer, since the answer did not say $\psi$ has to be quantifier-free. Thus your example above is of shape $\forall x\psi(x)$.

Answer (score 10):

A counterexample is a special case of a general claim: a case that shows the claim to be false. This is really just a matter of common sense and everyday logic that applies far beyond mathematics. It isn't usually regarded as something that needs formal definition. Once you have a counterexample, you know that the general claim isn't true, and that's the end to it.

Answer (score 7):

You can think of our knowledge of math as divided into (1) knowledge about mathematics itself—theorems of algebra, analysis, number theory, topology, etc.—and (2) knowledge about how to *do* mathematics—paradigmatic cases, heuristics for approaching a problem, counterexamples, etc.

Counterexamples are part of our knowledge of how to *do* mathematics. If you wanted a formal definition, I might say:

> If you have a statement such as "Every $X$ has the property $P$", a *counterexample* for the statement is an $X$ that doesn't have the property $P$.

Furthermore, you might have a good reason to believe that every $X$ has the property $P$:

- If *almost* every $X$ has property $P$. For example, "Every rational number has a multiplicative inverse" is true in every case except for 0.
- If you were formerly studying a special case where everything had the property $P$, and are now studying a more general case. For example, "Squaring a number makes it bigger." is true if you were only looking at natural numbers — but if you extend your view to numbers in $0<x<1$, the statement is false.
- If all of the "practical" examples you've seen have the property. For example, "all functions are continuous" is certainly not true. But if you are working with practical kinematics problems in physics, you may be used to functions that all have this property.

Counterexamples are one of the most important ways we organize our knowledge and sharpen our intuitions.

---

See also: Edwina Rissland wrote a dissertation on how we procedurally organize our knowledge of how to *do* mathematics:

https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/6928

Comment: What is the difference between an X and an instance of an X?

Comment: @JOHNCORCORAN Just awkward wording. I've fixed it. :)

Comment: To restate this using undergraduate logic, the classic counterexample is used to establish a logical statement in the form of "$p$ implies $p$" is false. The values for $p$ and $q$ that make "$p$ implies $q$" false are when $p$ is true and $q$ is false. So in terms of second or third year undergraduate logic, a more formal statement of this answer might be, "A counterexample is a statement for which $p$ is true and $q$ is false, which thereby shows that the statement '$p$ implies $q$' is false.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that formally, a counterexample to $$\forall(x \in X, y \in Y)\varphi$$ is a basically a substitution $(x:= x_0, y:= y_0)$ together with a proof that $$(x:= x_0, y:= y_0) \varphi \rightarrow \bot.$$

Unfortunately, this means that the "set-of-counterexamples function" fails to be preserved by equality of booleans. For instance, the booleans $$\forall x \in \mathbb{R},x+1=x \qquad \forall x \in \mathbb{R},x^2=x$$ are equal, in that they're both FALSE; but, the corresponding sets of counterexamples are different. For instance, $(x:=1)$ gives a counterexample to the former, but not to the latter.

(I don't know whether or not this is an actual problem.)

By the way, we can think of a substitution like $(x:= x_0,y:= y_0)$ as being a bit like an ordered tuple, in this case $(x_0,y_0)$. The difference is that the "order" is replaced by a name for each individual element; so in this case, $x_0$ is in the "$x$" position (rather than the 1st position) and $y_0$ is in the "$y$" position (rather than the 2nd position.) I think computer scientists call such things [records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_%28computer_science%29), which are viewed as elements of "named cartesian products" (aka "record types.")

Answer (score 0):

To use proof by counterexample, the original statement has to be of the form

"For all x, statement $A_x$ is true". (1)

Thus, showing that for some x, the statement $A_x$ is false, proves that the original statement is false. A formal definition of a counterexample could be "an example that proves a statement false" or something. This is a rigorous way of proof and I don't know what you mean by open questions. For a few examples, see http://www.math.toronto.edu/writing/Counterexample.pdf .

Also the following poof technique is sometimes referred to as counterexample:

- We have to prove statement S true
- Let us suppose that S is false
- Show that this leads to something that is false
- Thus, S has to be true